# python how to write error massages to error log and to main log using werkzeug logger in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

i like to write error messages to the additional error log AND to the main log
as currently all the output is written to the main log 
i set my log as this :

```
logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

server_logs_directory = 'logs/app/'
# Create handler
handler = RotatingFileHandler(server_logs_directory + "my_app_logger.log", maxBytes=20480000, backupCount=50)
# Create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s |--| %(name)s |--| %(levelname)s |--| %(message)s',
                              datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
# Add formatter to handler
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
# Add handler to logger
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

i can't find any way to add another handler for errors log file .

Answer (score 2):

You can set a level on the handler itself. Just add another handler to the same logger but only log errors with that handler.

```
err_handler = RotatingFileHandler(server_logs_directory + "my_app_errors.log", maxBytes=20480000, backupCount=50)
err_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(err_handler)
```

Comment: i did it but flask do not log the Traceback exceptions to this file , how can i make it 
log the Traceback when in flask I'm in info or debug mode ?